# How To Avoid Upload Large Videos in Angular?

Tags: angular, video, file-upload, html5-video

I have an angular application that allows you to upload images and videos. However, I want to avoid uploading videos that are longer than 30 seconds. My question is... considering the following [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-image-video-preview-final-ijhbye?file=app/app.component.ts) How do I prevent videos of a duration greater than 30 sec from loading? instead of deleting them after they have been loaded and displayed? Is it possible to achieve this goal using Angular?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, its possible

the idea is creating an object url, and loading it into a video element, this allows getting the properties of the video before uploading it to the server:

template:

```
<video #vid controls width="500px" id="vid" style="display:none"></video>
```

component:

```
@ViewChild("vid") ele: any;
onSelectFile(event) {
  const files = event.target.files;
  if (files) {
    for (const file of files) {
      const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      this.ele.nativeElement.src = objectUrl;
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (e: any) => {
        if (this.ele.nativeElement.duration > 30) {
            alert("movie is too long!");
        }
        this.mydata.push({
            url: e.target.result,
            type: "video"
        });
      }
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

Here is a [working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-image-video-preview-final-nqzesw?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: This solution Not working with videos downloaded from Whatsapp or when use a Safari Browser